# Remove space between UISearchBar and UINavigationBar (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Originally, I wanted the tint color of my search bar to be the same as the color of the navigation bar. However, the navigation bar has a transparent effect, and this affects the saturation of the color. So, I set the `transparent` property of the navigation bar to false. Now, they are the same color, but there is this large space between the two:[image]

How do I get rid of this space?

EDIT: COULD THIS BE BECAUSE OF A UITABLEVIEW I HAVE THAT IS IN THIS VIEW?
EDIT: [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using autolayout, this looks like the searchbar has a top constraint of 0 to the top layout guide. I don't know if this is a bug, but it causes the padding.

Make the top constraint 0 to the superview instead of the top layout guide or try a top constraint with a negative value (-20 - 44 = -64) to the top layout guide.